# Grammatical Rules of Construction or Logic to Resolve Some Seemingly Contradictory Legislation

Tags: grammar, logic, construction, contradiction

One of the things attorneys, such as myself, do often is argue over the meaning of a statute. Often this comes down to grammatical arguments about the location of commas, the use of conjunctions, etc. This is particularly challenging when it comes to poorly written legislation. California law has many such examples, but a particular pattern I’ve seen a few times now is for the statute to read something like this:

> “(b) The policy shall do all of the following: …(3) Prohibit the
>   surreptitious photographing or video-recording of pupils who are being
>   investigated. For purposes of this paragraph, “surreptitious
>   photographing or video-recording” means the covert collection of
>   photographic or videographic images of persons or places subject to an
>   investigation…” ([Cal. Ed. Code § 48204.2(b)(3)](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=EDC&sectionNum=48204.2.#:~:text=(1)%20Identify%20the%20circumstances%20upon,provided%20false%20or%20unreliable%20evidence))

Must the policy prohibit the photographing, etc. of all persons or places, or just pupils?

[Cal. Ed. Code § 48900.7](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=EDC&sectionNum=48900.7.) does the same type of thing:

> (a)…a pupil may be suspended from school or recommended for expulsion
>   if… the pupil has made terroristic threats against school officials or
>   school property, or both. (b) For the purposes of this section,
>   “terroristic threat” shall include any statement, whether written or
>   oral, by a person who willfully threatens to commit a crime which will
>   result in death, great bodily injury to another person or property
>   damage in excess of one thousand dollars ($1,000)…”

Does the statute require the threat be made against school officials or property, or simply against “another person”?

My general feeling is that although the definitions are broader than the scope of the initial provisions, their effect is limited to the term itself and does not extend to the qualifying language that follows the term’s introduction. That is, the policy applies only to pupils, and the threats must be made against school officials or property.

However, as I was not an English major nor even particularly good at English, I’m curious if there are other grammatical rules of construction or logic that definitively dictate the meaning of statements like these. Any help would be much appreciated.

As a side note, and in light of some of the comments, I'm willing to accept the possibility that I'm hoping for more than the rules of English Grammer can provide.

Comment: It's silly, the law. You could just ask the legislators what they meant, but no. I'm not a fan of literal interpretation; I like looking at intent. These laws were written by lawyers just like you in a manner of duress to try to satisfy everyone. If it's written badly, reasonable people can disagree.

Comment: Unfortunately (for you), there are very few "rules" that define the English language, just "practices" which are *usually* followed.  This is one reason why lawyers and legislators have invented their own "rules".

Comment: I think you can consider it something better and stronger than a "general feeling"--it is solid logic. In your second example, for instance, the definition defines a set of verbal actions as terroristic threats, but the sanction provided explicitly applies to only a particular subset of that set, as further defined in terms of who makes the threats and against whom or what.The ambiguity or contradiction of which you complain is just not there, finally.

Comment: @Hunter, Without a doubt, what you describe has been responsible for a LOT of nonsensical legislation. To get something passed into law requires both sides to be happy. Make the law too narrow and you lose the one; make it too broad and you lose the other. So instead it gets worded in such a way that allows both sides to argue the merits to their constituents and deprives everyone the ability to know what exactly is going on --It gets punted to the judiciary to figure out. I don't know this from experience, it's just always been my suspicion.

Comment: @Brian Donovan, Thank you for this, I tend to agree with you. I think what I might have alluded to as a contradiction is actually just superfluous, irrelevant, and partially redundant information in the definition that makes the whole thing smell of a contradiction. Those sections would make perfect sense if they said, for example, "For the purposes of the California Education Code", rather than limiting itself to just that section and implying that there's something more to the scope of the law than what is initially stated.

Comment: @Hunter, here are a couple of real problems in legislatures. First, most legislators are actually not lawyers. They have lawyers on staff, but they put their bill concepts together themselves before the staff translates them into legalese. A lot of inconsistencies are created through this process. And second, you don't have to ask the legislators what they meant. You can always check intent, because this is discussed in floor debate, and a transcript is always available. You might enjoy reading transcripts. Just go to any state legislature's web site.

Comment: @IsabelArcher It doesn't work that way. Whether you know the intent or are the author of the bill, it comes down to "what the law says." Unless you are a judge creating case law based on transcripts which may or may not answer your specific questions about meaning, the intent is legally moot.